# Xcode 10.2 -Visual studio 2019 - XamarinForms -TKCustomMaps crash

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maps

I am facing a particular crash after I updated visual studio 2019, Xcode 10.2. and iPhone 12.2
when I leave the map page is crashing. 
1.it opens fine the first time 
2.crashes during the next time I open the same page 
3. the crash will disappear if I comment the XAML for the map 
    Version
    Xamarin forms == 3.0.0...2510
    TKCustomMaps == 2.0.1
    NETStandarLibrary ==2.0.3
    XCode == 10.2

```
 xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:TK.CustomMap;assembly=TK.CustomMap" 
                          <tk:TKCustomMap x:Name="map" 
                            MapType="Street" 
                            IsClusteringEnabled="false" 
                            MapRegion="{Binding Region}"
                            Pins="{Binding Pins}"/>
```

I have tried almost everything -
 I deleted bin-object folders- restart and try to downgrade from visual studio 2019 to 2017,  but I can't figure out why. The version I have in production is working just fine on my phone with the new installed software 12.2

```
 at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<OnDispose>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:48 \n  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:152 \n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)\n  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 \n  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 \n  at app.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/btest/mb/app/iOS/Main.cs:17 "
```

Comment: Did you try clearing bin obj and other such methods?

Comment: I reported as a bug https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5899

Comment: Did xamarin respond to it?

Comment: no yet. I will have to stop using this library. because it hasn't been any update in about a year ago.

Comment: Why not use Xamarin Forms Maps?

Comment: let's say is more work and code to make it work. this nugget simplifies all the extra work.

Comment: Sounds good do tell me about the nuget! Thanks